# What are some new deep learning models for learning latent representation of data?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, autoencoders, latent-variable

I know that autoencoders are one type of deep neural networks that can learn the latent representation of data. I guess there should be several other models like autoencoders.

What are some new deep learning models for learning latent representation of data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a link to my answer on *CV Stack Exchange*, where I have mentioned about latent spaces and some deep learning models that learn these representations: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/442352/what-is-a-latent-space/442360#442360

In short, deep learning models for [Domain Adaptation](https://paperswithcode.com/task/domain-adaptation), [Computer Vision,](https://paperswithcode.com/area/computer-vision) [Natural Language Processing,](https://paperswithcode.com/area/natural-language-processing) [Recommendation Systems,](https://paperswithcode.com/task/recommendation-systems) [Music](https://paperswithcode.com/area/music)/[Speech](https://paperswithcode.com/area/speech)/[Audio](https://paperswithcode.com/area/audio) processing, [Adversarial models](https://paperswithcode.com/area/adversarial), etc., **all** learn some form of latent representation of data.

In fact, any place we're learning a function to map input and output spaces of a dataset, the model essentially learns a latent representation of data irrespective of whether the model is based on deep neural networks or a [stochastic method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_Dirichlet_allocation) or any other.